# Macro with conditional compilation

Tags: generics, rust, macros

In debug mode (`cfg!(debug_assertions)`) I've a struct `Foo` with 2 fields `{a:i16,only_in_debug:i16}` in release mode the struct has one field `{a:i16}`.

The function `sum` adds a number to `only_in_debug` field in debug mode but does do nothing in release mode (the field is missing).

I wrote a macro but in release mode doesn't work:

```rust
macro_rules! sum {
    ($a:expr,$b:expr)=>{
        if cfg!(debug_assertions) {
            $a+=$b;
        }
    }
}
```

struct in debug mode

```rust
#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: i16,
    pub only_in_debug: i16,
}

#[cfg(debug_assertions)]
impl Default for Foo {
    fn default() -> Foo {
        Foo {
            a: 0,
            only_in_debug: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

struct in release mode

```rust
#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: i16,
}

#[cfg(not(debug_assertions))]
impl Default for Foo {
    fn default() -> Foo {
        Foo {
            a: 0
        }
    }
}
```

main:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo::default();

    sum!(foo.only_in_debug, 10);
    println!("{:?}", foo); // (**)
}
```

running in debug mode the line (**) prints: `Foo { a: 0, only_in_debug: 10 }`

but in release mode says `^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unknown field`.

In C language it works using a preprocessor macro

```c
#ifdef NDEBUG

#define sum(a, b)

#else

#define sum(a, b) (a+=(b))

#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

The `cfg!` macro will evaluate to `true` or `false` at compile time but the code inside `if` will always be compiled, and so must typecheck. You need to attach a `#[cfg()]` attribute to an expression if you want the code to not be compiled if the `cfg` evaluates to false:

```rust
macro_rules! sum {
    ($a:expr, $b:expr)=>{
        #[cfg(debug_assertions)] {
            $a += $b;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```rust
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo { x: 1 };

    // This fails to compile.
    // if cfg!(target_pointer_width = "8") {
    //     foo.y;
    // }

    #[cfg(target_pointer_width = "8")]
    {
        foo.y;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bca2d078c5c30df98043fe0ee022fb6d)